# How does Android go about freeing up memory when low, and how does it restart them?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

*Please note the following vocabulary to avoid confusion*

1) When I say **reinstantiating** an activity, I mean `Activity.onCreate(bundle)`

2) When I say **starting from scratch** an activity, I mean `Activity.onCreate(null)`

*(Although I am not sure it makes a difference) For the purposes of this post, please assume that the Android applications I am interested in all have their activities launched in the same task*

### How does Android go about freeing memory from apps?

Lets say I have a phone. I am using many applications at once. I got bored of the current `Snapchat` application. So I press the home button and open `Facebook`. *Note that I did not press the back button, and so `Snapchat` lives on in the recent apps overview*.

Suddenly for some reason the phone is very low on memory and needs to start forcefully freeing up some from background apps.

- Will the Android OS kill **some** activities of `Snapchat` in order to free memory
- Will the Android OS kill **all** activities of `Snapchat` in order to free memory

### How does Android go about managing "killed" apps?

Now lets say I want to go back to `Snapchat`. I hit the overview button and select `Snapchat` from the scrolling list of recently used apps.

- Will the Android OS *reinstantiate* **some** activities of `Snapchat`
- Will the Android OS *reinstantiate* **all** activities of `Snapchat`
- Will the Android OS *reinstantiate* **zero** activities of `Snapchat` and just *starting from scratch* with the initial launcher activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DRD: all activities are killed.

The `ActivityManagerService` doesn't seem to kill anything anymore (it just forces GC calls and dispatches trim events).

```
if (false) {
   // For now we won't do this; our memory trimming seems
   // to be good enough at this point that destroying
   // activities causes more harm than good.
   if (curLevel >= ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE 
            && app != mHomeProcess && app != mPreviousProcess) {
       // Need to do this on its own message because the stack may not
       // be in a consistent state at this point.
       // For these apps we will also finish their activities
       // to help them free memory.
       mStackSupervisor.scheduleDestroyAllActivities(app, "trim");
   }
 }
```

Though when (if) it did try to kill something it would kill the whole process of a background app (it would simply call `kill -9 [PID]`). And since by default all your activities are run under one PID they all get destroyed when a process dies.

The same goes to the OOM and Low Memory Killers - the two operate with processes and make no distinction between your activities.

Please note, however, that some people claim that Android sometimes kills particular activities one by one on low memory. I failed to find any evidence of that in AOSP.

==============
Now, about restoring your app. I might not be an expert here cause this is connected to the Android's "Tasks and Back Stack System" which is way trickier than their tutorial videos make it seem.

The operation starts with calling `ActivityManager#moveTaskToFront(...)` and it eventually leads us to `ActivityManagerService#moveTaskToFrontLocked(...)`

There the OS will try to retrieve the stored task record associated with your app. If your app's been destroyed, the manager will have to go to `ActivityStackSupervisor#restoreRecentTaskLocked(...)` and if all goes well it's gona find the task and the back stack and do this for every activity in the task:

```
final ArrayList<ActivityRecord> activities = task.mActivities;
for (int activityNdx = activities.size() - 1; activityNdx >= 0; --activityNdx) {
   final ActivityRecord r = activities.get(activityNdx);
   mWindowManager.addAppToken(0, r.appToken, task.taskId, stack.mStackId,
     r.info.screenOrientation, r.fullscreen,
    (r.info.flags & ActivityInfo.FLAG_SHOW_ON_LOCK_SCREEN) != 0,
       r.userId, r.info.configChanges, task.voiceSession != null,
      r.mLaunchTaskBehind);
}
```

The same method (`WindowManager#addAppToken(...)`) is called when you start a new activity and it goes with a comment:

```
// Here it is!  Now, if this is not yet visible to the
// user, then just add it without starting; it will
// get started when the user navigates back to it.
```

So my **guess** is that when the OS restores an app it recreates the activity stack fully but only the topmost activity actually actually gets restarted. I guess, it's easy to set up an experiment to find out if I'm right here.

=======
One more update :) Yep, these two methods (`ActivityStackSupervisor#resumeTopActivitiesLocked()` and `ActivityStackSupervisor#resumeTopActivityLocked(...)`) are called a bit later. Though I really don't undesratnd why they resume activities in more than one stack - as I said, I'm definitely not an expert here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What do you think about my second question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean by "recreates the activity stack fully but only the topmost activity actually actually gets restarted". Could you clarify what you mean? **What do you mean by restart exactly?**

Comment: @AlanSTACK okay, "recreates the stack" stands for "sets up the activity stack again by adding ```ActivityRecord``` entities to it". And "only the topmost activity actually gets restarted" means "only the topmost activity in the said stack actually goes through the whole onCreate/onCreateView/onResume/... process". More info on activity stacks can be found in the "Tasks and Back Stack" tutorial on developer.android.com